# JS Alert when items collected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a maze game where the user must collect all the coins in the maze, however I am trying to make an alert appear once the user has collected all the coins, not in any particular order just in general. The alert is being very troublesome at the moment and not working correctly and I'm not sure where I am going wrong based off my research into the matter. I am new to JavaScript so apologies for any clear mistakes.

*EDIT* *I GOT TOLD TO REPHRASE MY QUESTION MORE DIRECTLY - SO THIS ISN'T A DUPLICATE QUESTION. I ALSO HAVE A MAP DECLARDED BUT CANNOT UPLOAD AS IT'S TOO MUCH CODE.*

*Also, when I say not working correctly, it will appear at random counts as supposed to when the last reward has been collected*.

```
var el = document.getElementById('game');

function drawWorld(){
    el.innerHTML = '';
    for(var y = 0; y < map.length ; y = y + 1) {
        for(var x = 0; x < map[y].length ; x = x + 1) {
        if (map[y][x] === 1) {
            el.innerHTML += "<div class='borders'></div>";
        } else if (map[y][x] === 2) {
            el.innerHTML += "<div class='reward'></div>";
        } else if (map[y][x] === 3) {
            el.innerHTML += "<div class='ground'></div>";
        } else if (map[y][x] === 5) {
            el.innerHTML += "<div class='character'></div>";
        } else if (map[y][x] === 4) {
                el.innerHTML += "<div class='ship'></div>";
            }
        }
        el.innerHTML += "<br>";
    }

    winGame();
}

function restartGame(){
    window.location.reload();
}

function winGame(){
if (!map[5].includes(2) && !map[2].includes(2) &&         
!map[3].includes(2) && !map[2].includes(2) && !map[4].includes(2) 
&&     !map[2].includes(2))
        alert("Well done!");
}


drawWorld();

document.onkeydown = function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 37){
        if ( map[character.y][character.x-1] !== 1){
            map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
            character.x = character.x - 1;
            map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
            drawWorld();
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 38){
        if ( map[character.y-1][character.x] !== 1){
            map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
            character.y = character.y - 1;
            map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
            drawWorld();
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 39){
        if ( map[character.y][character.x+1] !== 1){
            map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
            character.x = character.x + 1;
            map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
            drawWorld();
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40){
        if ( map[character.y+1][character.x] !== 1){
            map[character.y][character.x] = 3;
            character.y = character.y + 1;
            map[character.y][character.x] = 5;
            drawWorld();
        }
    }

    console.log(map)

}
```

Comment: What does "not working correctly" mean? What exact problem are you having? And, please always include the relevant HTML and CSS as well so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Updated the info, sorry.

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you without all the *relevant code*. That means HTML and CSS.

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: Are there errors in your browser's console? What does "troublesome" mean in programming terms?

Comment: Hmm... Why do you have `map[2].includes(2)` repeated 3 times in `winGame()`? That test doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Why dont you just keep a count of the coins collected and display an alert when it is equal to the total coins?